# c# MVC routing with constants

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm trying to generate an actionlink on a page that has the following route:
/{controller}/{type}/{sub}

The link needs to go to:
/{controller}/{type}/{sub}/new

How do I specify the "/new" portion of the url in an object or RouteValueDictionary so that I can pass it to the HTML.ActionLink?

StackOverflow won't let me answer my question for another 8hrs... so:

Thanks Justin.
Your suggestion worked, but for the sake of completeness, I discovered the method using the Html.ActionLink method:

You just need to specify the ActionName of the method that resolves that route. The framework appears to automatically work out that you want it on the same path as the current page.

So, if your route is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "New", // Route name
            "{controller}/{type}/{sub}"/new, // URL with parameters
            new {controller = "DefaultController", action = "Create", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

The link is:

```
Html.ActionLink("Create New Page", "Create")
```

Approving Justin's method as it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the default implementations of ActionLink do not support this, so you have the following options:

Build it manually in this case (I am not in front of Visual Studio, so the syntax might be off a little)

```
<a href="@Url.Action(
    "Controller", "Method", new { type = "type", sub = "sub" }));/new">
    link text</a>
```

Or, you could [create a new helper method](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) to encapsulate something like this, if it happens often enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "New", // Route name
                "{controller}/{type}/{sub}"/{new}, // URL with parameters
                new {controller = "DefaultController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{type}/{sub}", // URL with parameters
                new {controller = "DefaultController", action = "Index"});
```

should be something like that

Comment: I do not think the question is about routing, but about creating the link.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the route as AD.Net suggests above and then use the Html.RouteLink extension helper to create the link, this way, if you ever decide to change the url/link it's automatically picked up by the routing engine

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "New", // Route name
                "{controller}/{type}/{sub}"/{new}, // URL with parameters
                new {controller = "DefaultController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

`Html.RouteLink("Create New Page", "New")`